# How to Navigate via MaterialPageRoute in a TabBarView?

Tags: flutter, dart

1. I want to Navigate to the second Tab via a Button in the TabBarView.
2. Can anyone help with how is it done via Navigator.of(_).push(MaterialPageRouce(....)?

[image]

> **Note: I am routed though, but to a different(like the 1st image below)**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a push, you can use `DefaultTabController` to change the current index using `animateTo`. You need to wrap `IconButton` in a `Builder` since `DefaultTabController` is accessed in the same widget where it's created.

```dart
Builder(
    builder: (context) => IconButton(
        icon: icon,
        onPressed: () {
            DefaultTabController.of(context).animateTo(1); // 1 is index of 2nd tab (cart tab).
        },
    ),
);
```

Comment: Superb! it worked. Is it the only method to do this? Just curious.

Comment: Awesome! You can do `DefaultTabController.of(context).index = 1;` as well instead of `animateTo`.